# Calculating the flux of $\langle x,y,x\rangle$ over $z=1-x-y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Find the flux of $\bar F = \langle x, y, x\rangle$ over $z = 1 - x - y$ in the first octant

use the upward unit normal ($\bar n$)

flux = $\int\int_S \bar F \cdot \bar n dA$

$dS = \sqrt 3 dA$

$\bar n = 1/\sqrt 3 \times\langle-1, -1, 1\rangle$

Flux = $\int_0^1\int_0^{-x+1}(-y) dydx = -1/6$

What am I doing wrong? I don't think I should be getting a negative value if I used the upward normal. I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Another hint: Your positive unit normal is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$z=1-x-y\ \equiv 0=1-(x+y+z);\text{where}\;x,y,z\geq 0$$

Is the definition of a [$2$-simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex): Its a plane with unit normal pointing along the unit vector $\langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\rangle$.

[image]

Now, what is $F\cdot \langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\rangle$?

Does this simplify your calculation of the integral?